# Cypher: Matching nodes in a nested FOREACH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a nested FOREACH loop that needs to match a tag to multiple labels.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a: Article {URL: event.URL})

FOREACH(ignoreme in case when a is  null then [1] else [] end |
CREATE (a: Article {URL: event.URL})
//other statements ..... //
FOREACH (relation in CASE WHEN event.article.nlp_relations is not null then event.article.nlp_relations else [] end |

         match (a)-[:HAS_NLP_TAG]->(t_from) where (t_from:Tag or t_from:Entity) and t_from.value = relation.from.value
        match (a)-[:HAS_NLP_TAG]->(t_to) where (t_to:Tag or t_to:Entity) and t_to.value = relation.to.value
        call apoc.create.relationship(t_from,relation.type , {}, t_to)
)     
 )
```

This does not work because you cannot use a match inside a foreach. I can say that there will always be a node to match as it will be created earlier in the same query. so it will never be null, but I do not know how to express this in this current form. Can anybody help

Comment: Do the "other statements ....." create `HAS_NLP_TAG` relationships from the newly-created `a` node? If not, then the `MATCH` clauses would never match.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just reformulate your second `FOREACH` as a normal `MATCH`-`CREATE` combination, something like (I didn't try to run it):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a: Article {URL: event.URL})

FOREACH(ignoreme in case when a is  null then [1] else [] end |
  CREATE (a: Article {URL: event.URL}
)
//other statements ..... //
unwind Case When event.article.nlp_relations is null then [] else event.article.nlp_relations end as relation
match (a)-[:HAS_NLP_TAG]->(t_from) where (t_from:Tag or t_from:Entity) and t_from.value = relation.from.value
match (a)-[:HAS_NLP_TAG]->(t_to) where (t_to:Tag or t_to:Entity) and t_to.value = relation.to.value
call apoc.create.relationship(t_from,relation.type , {}, t_to)
)
```

You might still need to insert an appropriate `WITH`-Statement before the `MATCH`-statements.

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for your reply, my problem is that I actually do not what it to run if there is already a match, because it means that the tags are already there, and for that reason i put it in the first ` FOREACH `

Comment: although I believe  a boolean earlier on will do the trick, then case can involve the boolean, I'll get back to you

Comment: You can "interrupt" the execution by noting that the execution does not continue beyond a failing `MATCH` or beyond an emtpy `UNWIND`, so something like `with [] as a unwind a as b return b` never reaches the `RETURN`.